# How to correctly polyfill Intl locale data

Tags: javascript, internationalization, aurelia, i18next

I'm a little confused about how to actually polyfill certain common locale data (CLDR) from the [Intl polyfill](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/#locale-data).

What I understand so far is the following (please correct me if I'm wrong here):

- Modern browsers ship the locale data themselves (no polyfill needed whatsoever)
- `Intl.min` comes without any locale data
- `Intl.complete` comes with all locale data from `intl/locale-data` bundled

Since we only need to support some locales (lets say `en` & `de`) it'd be wise to only bundle `Intl.min` and dynamically load the CLDR when needed (on app start or when the user changes the language).

How do I dynamically load the CLDR when needed & how do I add it to `Intl`?

I've got `aurelia-i18n` & `i18next` already set up so that they load our custom translations only when needed using the `i18next-xhr-backend`. Can I somehow hook into this & also load the needed locale from the `Intl` polyfill?

- If so, how do I do this and how do I check beforehand on whether it is necessary or not (new browsers don't need it and it could already be loaded)?
- Am I correct in the assumption that I don't have to manually add the locale after it has been loaded since it does this itself (e.g. `intl/locale-data/jsonp/en.js` starts with `IntlPolyfill.__addLocaleData(...);`)?

Answer (score 0):

The [intl polyfills repo](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/) shows how you can load only the necessary CLDR data via a CDN service as [described here](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/#intljs-and-ft-polyfill-service)

Aurelia itself takes care whether the polyfill is [needed at all](https://github.com/aurelia/i18n/blob/master/src/aurelia-i18n.js#L67) the only exception here is if you're distributing a bundled production build, where you'd have to make sure the file is already contained in the bundle. Depending on your setup/module loader this might vary.

As for loading additional locales yes you're right just requiring the file should patch the window object to provide your additional translations. 
In order to check which ones are needed you can use the [supportedLocalesOf method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat/supportedLocalesOf) of either the Number/Date formatter

So calling

```
console.log(Intl.NumberFormat.supportedLocalesOf("de-DE"))
```

Will likely result in ["de-DE"] in your browser if it has the necessary locale otherwise (you can try it out in node) in an empty array

Comment: Loading all CLDRs upfront from CDN via a script tag is no option since this would statically load all on page start no matter which ones are actually used. I'm distributing a bundled production build which contains the INTL polyfill (no problem so far). What I still don't know: Where can I "hook myself in" to dynamically load the CLDR data only when needed (language change etc.)?

Comment: Aurelia fires [a custom event](https://github.com/aurelia/i18n/blob/master/src/i18n.js#L57) when locale changes happen. At that position you can do an ajax request for the missing locale, just make sure the files are distributed but not bundled. If you know for sure those locales will be needed check the answers supportedLocalesOf approach.